# All my apps crashing upon startup, black screen

Tags: custom-roms, crashes

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 with a flashed ROM Gingerbread (Kyrillos) and Kernel (EX Kernel). When i power on my phone it loads up to the lock screen, but it just shows a blank screen And i'm prompted to force close on every single app over and over. The only thing i can do Is access my phone in disk mode on my PC.  I have tried removing the SD Card, Clearing all the cache files in Recovery but it still doesn't fix the problem (Second Time this has happened)

It is very annoying as to why this happens, i wasnt even using my phone at the time, it was just charging.  Is there any possible way of fixing this without a reflash or format?

Comment: This looks like a force-close-loop. Have you installed any app lately, immediately before the problem started? You might want to look into the [safe-mode tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) for some first aid.

Comment: I spent all afternoon flashing, restoring, importing apps etc. I just restarted my phone the first time after doing so and its just done it again. I give up :(

Comment: Too fast, *far* too fast. You did one step too much: "importing apps". Skip that. Flash, yes. Reconfigure, yes. But do not immediately start importing all your apps. First see if everything runs smootly again, then install (import) the first app. Again, watch it for a while, before you continue with the next app. As soon as your problem re-appears, you might have discovered the culprit: remove the last app installed, or restart the process and *skip* that app to find out if there is more than one involved.

Comment: I actually just installed apps via play, no new apps. Will it affect it anyway if i restore my settings from my google acc? i've always wondered that.

Comment: If it's the settings which are "borked": sure. Trouble with that Google Backup is: You cannot restore it "on demand", only "on reset". And then only the last state. So if you reset and decide not to restore, there's no such thing as "later" or "next time". You've got to use a "real backup" for that. Hint, if your device runs 4.0+: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575). // Wherever you re-install from: one app at a time, the next only if you're sure everything is still OK.